# jquery load from Generic Handler

Tags: jquery, handler

I have this method in Generic Handler it takes the id from a query string and sends all the like values to a jquery function to fill the label

```
<div class="voteDown">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDeslick"  runat="server"   data-id='<%# Eval("CommentId") %>' CssClass="A1" ClientIDMode="Static">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>    
        <asp:Label ID="lblDesLike" runat="server"    Text='<%# Bind("CommentDesLike") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"   CssClass="A2" ></asp:Label>        
    </asp:LinkButton>
</div>
```

this is the Generic Handler Code

```
int commentId = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["CommentiD"]);
NewsCommentLikesEntity obj = new NewsCommentLikesEntity();
var Ilist = obj.SelectAll();

foreach (EML.Models.SpNewsCommentsLikes_SelectAll_Result row in Ilist){
    var TotalCommentLikes = row.CommentDesLike;
    context.Response.Write(TotalCommentLikes);
}
```

and for the Jquery

```
function LikeEvent(Comment) {
    $(".A1").click(function () {
        var CommentiD = $(this).data("id");
        if (CommentiD == null) {
            var CommentiD = Comment;
        }
        //var NewsId =41
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '../Searis/Test.ashx?CommentiD=' + CommentiD,
            dataType: "json",
            //data:{id:CommentiD},
            success: function (jsonData) {
                var commentLikesTotal = jsonData; 
                $('.A2,#lblDesLike').text(commentLikesTotal);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
};
```

The problem is that jsonData returns 01010101010, it fills every lblDesLike with this value. I try to get the lblDesLike id but it's always take the first id not the one that i've clicked, so i don't know how to fill every lblDesLike with his own value.

Comment: *"it's always take the first id"* - What specifically do you mean by that?  Are you re-using `id` values in the HTML?  That's invalid.

Comment: What @David said, you are reusing ID's which is invalid HTML. You can use jQuery context though, to avoid targeting all of them. Save a reference to the .A1 you clicked with var self = this;  and then use self as context in your $(".A2, #lblDesLike", self).text() selector.

Comment: when i click A1 it's give me the id that i need but it don't  give me the id of  lblDesLike  they have the same id ,when i try to put it in html tag 
data-id2='<%# Eval("CommentId") %>'
in  lblDesLike it's gave me  the first id only  and i relay don't know how can i fill all the values that comes from the jsonData  to set every value to his own

Comment: @Brunis  what u said work for me but what i need is i want to fill every value in it's one in one click your idea is  filling one value